# Exportar procedimientos almacenados desde MySQL con phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

¿Cómo puedo exportar solamente los procedimientos almacenados desde MySQL?

Solo me figuran las tablas... Intenté quitando la estructura, pero tampoco.

He visto que lo hacen desde aquí, pero no logro encontrar la forma.

**Favor omitir soluciones por linux o consola...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión usas de phpmyadmin? En mi versión (3.4.11.1deb2+deb7u8) si seleccionas exportar sólo estructura te exporta los procedimientos almacenados y los iniciadores también después de la creación de la tabla asociada al iniciador o iniciadores.

Comment: debo seleccionar todas las tablas ? o des seleccionarlas todas? algún otro ticket? mysql 5.5.24

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmarme la versión de tu phpmyadmin? Es probable que sea demasiado antiguo y que no soporte la exportación de procedimientos almacenados y/o iniciadores.

Comment: phpmyadmin 3.5.1

Comment: En mi caso particular, tras seleccionar la base de datos deseada, pulso en "Exportar" y lo único que cambio de las opciones por defecto es: Método de exportación > Personalizado, Opciones específicas al formato > Volcar tabla > estructura. Y sólo con eso al pulsar en exportar me exporta toda la estructura (tablas, iniciadores y procedimientos). Prueba a cambiar el tema de phpmyadmin. Yo uso "pmahomme".

Comment: disculpa, esta en especial es la 2.9.1

Comment: He abierto una sala de chat para seguir buscando la solución.
 [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82869/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-francisco-acevedo).